# Sending GCM from ios device trough PHP to android

Tags: php, android, ios

i want to send notifications to android and iphone.
on this moment i can send from android to android using a standard GCM API.
when i call the ios PHP script from android the message is send to and received on the iphone.
but when i tried to send from ios to android trough PHP with a hardcoded regid, the PHP script echos that the message is send but i dont receive it on the android.
can someone please help me?